# Problems with asset pipeline in Heroku: not loading some images and js files in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

My app works in the development environment but in Heroku there are some images, fonts, and js functions that aren't working.

I will hone in on one image for now. The homepage should load an image located in

> assets/images/patterns/blue_pattern.gif

In my SCSS file I have:

```
image-url("patterns/blue_pattern.gif")
```

My Heroku logs contains the following:

> 2017-04-11T10:39:54.873200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/images/patterns/blue_pattern.gif"
>   host=matchmeplease.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=cf0c2d58-a616-484f-b659-cd4cbfe94118 fwd="115.70.240.190"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1789
>   protocol=https

I will be honest and say I do not fully understand the configuation files.

My config/environments/production.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.serve_static_assets = true
end
```

config/application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'
require 'geocoder'
require "geocoder/railtie"
Geocoder::Railtie.insert

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MatchMe
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "font")
  end
end
```

EDIT: After following Uday kumar das' comment (see below) I now have images and fonts working, but my js files still aren't loading for some reason.

When I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get the following:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
/home/ubuntu/workspace/matchme/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/matchme/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/matchme/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm not sure why this is because my AWS S3 function works perfectly fine in my app.

Comment: Did you run a rake assets:precompile?

Comment: Yeah. Right now the only thing that's not working in Heroku are the js files.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/application.rb` add below code and `bundle` it:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

After this run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

For more details visit https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: Hey, thank you!! That seemed to work for the images and fonts, but the js files still aren't working. I'll post what happens when I run the bundle exec command.

Comment: Welcome!! Check your browser console for any errors in JS files.

Comment: No errors. For some reason the js files just aren't loading in production.